# capturing `echon` messages displayed from `job_start()`

Tags: vim

I am writing some tests for a Vim plugin to ensure that certain behavior is done correctly. This plugin uses `echon` in addition to `echohl` to display messages.

Is there any native VimScript command I can use to detect what is currently displayed as part of the `echon` message?

In Vim versions earlier than 8, before the async support, I was able to capture the string from `echon` by using `redir` and calling the plugin directly. With Vim 8 and having the plugin using `job_start` with a handler for `close_cb` the `echon` is done asynchronously, and I am no longer able to catch it with `redir`.

The `echon` call is simple:

```
    redraw
    let message = "Unable to parse output. If using a plugin that alters the default output, consider disabling it. See :Pytest session"
    let length = strlen(message) + 1
    hi YellowBar ctermfg=black ctermbg=yellow guibg=#e5e500 guifg=black
    echohl YellowBar
    echon message . repeat(" ",&columns - length)
    echohl
```

Ideally, I would like to have a way of ensuring that this message is displayed, regardless of the async behavior. I am considering enabling a debug or testing setting to also send the message to `echom`, but that defeats a bit the purpose of really ensuring that the actual `echon` is displayed.

Comment: Did you consider using `:help :echomsg` instead of `:help :echon`?

Comment: As I explained in the description, I would prefer *not* to change to `echom`.

Comment: Why? They work the same except one can be retrieved later and the other can't.

Comment: The plugin can get run dozens of times per buffer, this would add a tremendous amount of clutter in `:messages`. I would prefer not to have to do that just to be able to support async behavior testing.